# GCMBroadcastReceiver in oreo(8.0) or up not working

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

GCMBroadcastReceiver  not register using manifest or dynamically

```
<receiver
            android:name="com.ee.nowmedia.core.pushnotification.PushBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter><!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" /><!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.ee.nowmedia.core.pushnotification" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Answer (score 2):

As of April 10, 2018, Google has deprecated **GCM**. The **GCM** server and client APIs are deprecated and will be removed as soon as April 11, 2019. Migrate GCM apps to [Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/), which inherits the reliable and scalable GCM infrastructure, plus many new features. See the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm) to learn more. Read more at [Google Cloud Messaging -- DEPRECATED 4/10/2018](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client)
 documentation

So the code

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        ......
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

is useless since 8.0 and also after 11Apr2019 for each API.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the above answer that GCM is deprecated. Migrate From GCM to FCM and it is quite easy. You just have to create a class extending FirebaseMessagingService class.

Register Service class in Manifest.

```
    <service
        android:name=".fcm.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        tools:ignore="ExportedService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

and this is how your MyFirebaseMessagingService class looks like.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onNewToken(String s) {
    super.onNewToken(s);
    //Here you will get your FCM ID/Token
    Log.d(TAG, "onNewToken: " + s);
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    //This method is used for handling incoming notifications
}}
```

That's all. FCM Done